# Is it possible to display 3D view of multiple DWG and Revit models together in a viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have loaded Two models one is .dwg and Second one is .rvt in web viewer using Autodesk Forge API.
I want to see both files in 3D view in viewer But it shows .rvt file in 3D and .dwg file in 2D.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately loading both 2D and 3D models onto one scene is not supported yet.

However you can have two Viewer instances in one page - see a sample in point here: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-navigation.sample